# Jquery set label's attribute 'for'

Tags: jquery, html

I have a few labels that look like this :

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="boy1">
<label id="lblboy1" for="boy1" class="gender"></label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="boy2">
<label id="lblboy2" for="boy2" class="gender"></label>
```

How can I use jquery to change the value of the "for" attribute?

What I tried is something like this:

```
  $("#lblboy1").attr('for', 'boy3');
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Do you wrap the code inside document ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work just fine. Are you sure jQuery is loaded properly and that you're executing the code after the DOM is ready?

Here's an example of using jQuery to change the label of Boy 1 to select the Boy 3 input:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lblboy1").attr("for", "boy3");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="gender" id="boy1">
<label id="lblboy1" for="boy1" class="gender">Boy 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="boy2">
<label id="lblboy2" for="boy2" class="gender">Boy 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="boy3">
<label id="lblboy3" for="boy3" class="gender">Boy 3</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your jquery is inside $(document).ready function or similar.

Comment: its working fine for me. just try in your and let me know